# Why am getting runtime error in doInBackground() in android?

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I am getting runtime error of in the following method:

```
 public class ReverseGeocodeLookupTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, GeoCodeResult> {

            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Please wait...contacting Yahoo!", // title
                        "Requesting reverse geocode lookup", // message
                        true // indeterminate
                );
            }


//Location of the error
           @Override
            protected GeoCodeResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return geoCoder.reverseGeoCode(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(GeoCodeResult result) {
                this.progressDialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            }

        }



}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Comment: try this.progressDialog.dismiss();